# Call Write-Host on the results of a call to Get-Content

Tags: powershell, file-io

The following code:

```
$values = Get-Content ./values.yaml
Write-Host $values
```

Gives the error:

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Message'. Specified method is not supported.

Running `Write-Host $values.ToString()` does not give an error, but it only outputs the text of "System.Object[]".

**How can I use Write-Host to output the text of this file?**

NOTE: I would also like to preserve the line endings in the file.  (I just found that `Write-Host "$values"` will give the text, but the line endings are gone.)

<sub><sup>(Note, I really am going to be using Write-Verbose, but Write-Host is similar and easier to test and ask about.)</sup></sub>

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using `Write-Host`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - As I said in the bottom of my post, I really plan to use `Write-Verbose`.  The 3rd party system I am integrating this with will log it at a "Verbose" level if I use `Write-Verbose`.  But it is easier to write and debug the question with `Write-Host`.

Comment: The short answer is that `Get-Content` alone returns an array of lines. You can use `-Raw` to return the contents as a single string. More detail available in the linked question's answers!

Comment: @braintist- Thank you!  Sad thing is I think this has got me before!  I am going to leave this here as a "signpost" for my future self rather than delete it.

Comment: @Vaccano happens to the best of us, I still sometimes put commas between arguments to commands in PowerShell ‍♂️and other mistakes I should really know better about 

Comment: For your future self, as previous comments `-Raw` works perfect for what you need, in addition if you want to convert objects into a `multiline-string` you can use `Out-String`. i.e.: `Write-Host (Get-Service | Out-String)` will return a string representation of the object instead of the object type `System.Object[]`.